# Activities enter onCreate all the time

Tags: android

I am getting crazy with a problem...

The point is, I have an Activity called LogIn. This is how it is declared on the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".LogIn"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

I was reading that after writing *`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation`*, the application was not entering on onCreate again when you were changing the orientation.

The problem is that my application is entering onCreate ALL THE TIME. I am debugging using Eclipse, and when I open the app, enters (that´s normal), then, if I wait until the phone is off, enters again on onCreate!!, after, I turn it on and it enters again!!.
I thought that when the app was "behind" another one it was entering on onPause, and then, when it was comming back from background, the Activity was going to onResume(), but no....on my app it is going to onCreate() again....

I don´t know what to do for my application to work properly......

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your application targets `API level 13` you should add `screenSize`

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That was exactly my problem! Now I don´t have this problem anymore!!